# Find all three complex solutions of the equation $z^3=-10+5i$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$. I want to calculate the three solutions of the equation $z^3=-10+5i$. Give the result in cartesian and in exponential representation.

Let $z=x+yi $.

Then we have $$z^2=(x+yi)^2 =x^2+2xyi-y^2=(x^2-y^2)+2xyi$$

And then $$z^3=z^2\cdot z=[(x^2-y^2)+2xyi]\cdot [x+yi ] =(x^3-xy^2)+2x^2yi+(x^2y-y^3)i-2xy^2=(x^3-3xy^2)+(3x^2y-y^3)i$$

So we get
$$z^3=-10+5i \Rightarrow (x^3-3xy^2)+(3x^2y-y^3)i=-10+5i \\ \begin{cases}x^3-3xy^2=-10 \\ 3x^2y-y^3=5\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}x(x^2-3y^2)=-10 \\ y(3x^2-y^2)=5\end{cases}$$

Is everything correct so far? How can we calculate $x$ and $y$ ? Or should we do that in an other way?

Comment: Correct so far. (You could develop z3 more directly, using the binomial formula.) No more idea :-(

Comment: I think it is far more useful here to use the absolute value $|z|$ and the argument $arg(z)$ of a complex number.

Comment: So, *you just need to take the cube root of $-10+5i$*. This is only slightly harder than taking roots of a real number, there will be three different solutions, and there is a standard procedure to follow. It is probably explained in your textbook or on your lessons, and see also e.g. here: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/A_First_Course_in_Linear_Algebra_(Kuttler)/06:_Complex_Numbers/6.03:_Roots_of_Complex_Numbers

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Write $-10+5i$ in its polar form, then recognize the exponential has period $2\pi i$. Use this fact to take the cube root of both sides and obtain all solutions. Once you have the solutions, you can find individual real and imaginary parts.

Comment: We have that $-10=r\cos\theta$ and $5=r\sin\theta$ and so we get $-\frac{1}{2}=\tan\theta \Rightarrow \theta=\arctan\left (-\frac{1}{2}\right )$ and replacing this in one of the equations we get $\theta$. Is that correct?

Comment: @MaryStar: Yes, you have the right idea. From here, you have to be careful since the complex number $z=-10+5i$ is in the second quadrant but $\theta=\arctan(-1/2)$ corresponds to the fourth quadrant. To accommodate this discrepancy, you'll need to take $\theta=\pi+\arctan(-1/2)=\pi-\arctan(1/2)$. Now you can use the polar form $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ and apply the fact that $e^{i\theta}=e^{i\theta+2n\pi i}$ for any $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I haven;t really understood why we need $+\pi$ at $\theta$. Could you explain that to me further?

Comment: The range of $\arctan(x)$ is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. For example, consider the points in the $xy$-plane $(1,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$. Both points would give $\theta=\arctan(-1)=-\pi/4$, but $(-1,1)$ is in the second quadrant which means its polar angle should be between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$. This comes back to the fact that the tangent has period $\pi$, and the range of $\arctan(x)$ is between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. When dealing with points like those above, we have to add $\pi$ to the output value to compensate for $\arctan(x)$ not having all angles between $0$ and $2\pi$. @MaryStar

Answer (score 4):

The *exact* algebraic answer, which expressible in terms of *real quantities* by *real-valued* radicals, is:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\begin{align}&x=-\alpha_k\sqrt [3]{\frac{5}{3\alpha_k^2-1}}\\
&y=-\sqrt [3]{\frac{5}{3\alpha_k^2-1}}\end{align}}$$

where,

$$\begin{align}\alpha_k=-2+2\sqrt{5}\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arccos\left(-\frac{2\sqrt 5}{5}\right)-\frac{2\pi k}{3}\right)\end{align}$$
for $k\in\{0,1,2\}\thinspace .$

---

$\rm Construction:$

In this answer, we find all pairs of $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^{2}$ in terms of real quantities by *real-valued* radicals.

After expanding the parentheses, we have:

$$\begin{align}&\begin{cases}x(x^2-3y^2)=-10 \\y(3x^2-y^2)=5\end{cases}\\
\implies &\frac xy\left(\frac {\frac {x^2}{y^2}-3}{\frac {3x^2}{y^2}-1}\right)=-2\end{align}$$

Substituting $\dfrac xy=u$, leads to:

$$\begin{align}&\frac{u(u^2-3)}{3u^2-1}=-2\\
\implies &u^3+6u^2-3u-2=0\end{align}$$

We have $3$ distinct real roots, however this is the case of [Casus irreducibilis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).

Using the key substitution $u=v-2$, yields:

$$v^3-15v+20=0$$

We know that, the depressed monic cubic equation $x^3+px+q=0$ is solved by

$$\begin{align}x_k=2\sqrt{-\frac{p}{3}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arccos\left(\frac{3q}{2p}\sqrt{\frac{-3}{p}}\right)-\frac{2\pi k}{3}\right) \quad \text{for} \quad k=0,1,2.\end{align}$$

Thus we obtain:

$$\begin{align}u_k=-2+2\sqrt{5}\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arccos\left(-\frac{2\sqrt 5}{5}\right)-\frac{2\pi k}{3}\right) \quad \text{for} \quad k=0,1,2.\end{align}$$

Finally, setting $\dfrac xy=\alpha\,$ we get:

$$\begin{align}&y(3y^2\alpha^2-y^2)+5=0\\
\implies &(3\alpha^2-1)y^3+5=0\\
\implies &y^3=-\frac{5}{3\alpha^2-1}\\
\implies &y=-\sqrt [3]{\frac{5}{3\alpha^2-1}}\\
\implies &x=-\alpha\sqrt [3]{\frac{5}{3\alpha^2-1}}\end{align}$$

where $\alpha\in\{u_0,u_1,u_2\}\thinspace.$

---

Note that, casus irreducibilis cannot be solved in radicals in terms of real quantities, it *can* be solved trigonometrically in terms of real quantities.

Therefore, we can no longer escape the general *trigonometric* or another *non-algebraic* representations.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct so far. Note that\begin{align}-10+5i&=5\sqrt5\left(-\frac2{\sqrt5}+\frac i{\sqrt 5}\right)\\&=5\sqrt5\exp\left(\left(\pi-\arctan\left(\frac12\right)\right)i\right).\end{align}Therefore, if $\alpha=\pi-\arctan\left(\frac12\right)$, then $z^3=-10+5i$ if and only if $z$ is one of the numbers$$\sqrt5\exp\left(\frac\alpha3i\right),\ \sqrt5\exp\left(\frac{\alpha+2\pi}3i\right)\text{ or }\sqrt5\exp\left(\frac{\alpha+4\pi}3i\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

There is another way
$$z^3+10-5i=0$$
Let's replace the complex number with a constant $a$
$$z^3+a=0$$
$$z^3+(a^{1/3})^3=0$$
Using the Sum of Cubes
$$(z+a^{1/3})(z^2-a^{1/3}z+a^{2/3})=0$$
We get $z=-a^{1/3}$ as a solution
$$z^2-a^{1/3}z+a^{2/3}=0$$
$$z=\frac{-(-a^{1/3})±\sqrt{(-a^{1/3})^2-4(1)(a^{2/3})}}{2(1)}=\frac{a^{1/3}±\sqrt{-3a^{2/3}}}{2}=\frac{a^{1/3}±\sqrt3ia^{1/3}}{2}$$
$$=\left(\frac{1±i\sqrt3}{2}\right)a^{1/3}=a^{1/3}e^{±\pi i/3}$$
Now we find the cube root of $a$ using polar form
$$(10-5i)^{1/3}=\left(\sqrt{10^2+5^2}\exp\left(i\arctan\left(-\frac{5}{10}\right)\right)\right)^{1/3}$$$$=\left(5\sqrt5\exp\left(-i\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\right)^{1/3}=\sqrt{5}\exp\left(\frac{-i}{3}\arctan{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$
**WE GET THE SOLUTION**
$${z=\sqrt{5}\exp\left(\frac{-i}{3}\arctan{\frac{1}{2}}\right)e^{k\pi i/3}}, k=-1,0,1$$
NOTE:
Instead of using the sum of cubes, we can notice the following
$$z^3=-a$$
$$z^3=ae^{k\pi i}, k=-1,1,3$$

Take the cube root on both sides
$$z=(ae^{k\pi i})^{1/3}=a^{1/3}e^{k\pi i/3}, k=-1,1,3$$
Then find the cube root and finish

Comment: When we do the way that you mentioned in NOTE, then are the solutions in exponential form :  \begin{equation*}z_1=(10-5i)^{1/3}e^{-\pi i/3}, \ z_2=(10-5i)^{1/3}e^{\pi i/3}, \ z_3=(10-5i)^{1/3}e^{\pi }\end{equation*}  Or how do we write the solutions in exponential form?

Comment: @MaryStar I've edited my answer to clarify. Yes, those are the answers, but $z_3$ has $e^{\pi i}$ not $e^\pi$

Comment: Do we not have to compute also $(10-5i)^{1/3}$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar I did. It's been in the answer

Comment: Ah yes, sorry! We shall give the result in cartesian and in exponential form. Is your solution the  exponential form?

Comment: Mine is in exponential form

Comment: Which is the cartesian form? Do we have to write this in the form $z=x+yi$ ?

Comment: Cartesian form is $z=x+yi$. Exponential form is $z=re^{i\theta}$ Wwe can switch back and forth with the formulas:
$$re^{i\theta}=r\left(\cos{\theta}+i\sin\theta\right)$$
$$x+yi=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{i\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}$$

Comment: Great! I got it! Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a primitive third root of unity,  say $\zeta_3=e^{\frac {2\pi i}3}.$

Take $\omega $ with $w^3=-10+5i$, say $\omega =-\sqrt {125}^{\frac 13}e^{\frac{i\arctan -\frac 12}3}=-\sqrt 5e^{\frac{i\arctan -\frac 12}3}.$

Then the roots are $\{\omega, \zeta_3 \omega, \zeta_3 ^2\omega \}.$